# Client: recv transport endpoint not connected

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am trying to implement a client-server program.
However, while the server program runs fine, the client program exits with the error::
recv: transport endpoint not connected.
Its been puzzling me for quite a while now. Some help will be greatly appreciated!
Here is the server program ::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int sockid,newsockid,pid;
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr,clientaddr;
    socklen_t x;
    x=sizeof(clientaddr);
    char msg[20];
    sockid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockid == -1)
        perror("SOCKET");
    memset(&myaddr,0,sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port=htons(8888);
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(sockid,(const struct sockaddr *)&myaddr,sizeof(myaddr)) == -1)
        perror("bind");
    listen(sockid,5);
    newsockid=accept(sockid,(struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr,&x);
    if(newsockid == -1)
        perror("accept");
    printf("NEW CLIENT ADDR:: %s",ntohs(clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr));
    pid=fork();
    while(1)
    {   
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            memset(msg,'\0',20);
            if(recv(newsockid,msg,sizeof(msg),0) == -1)
                perror("recv");
            puts(msg);
            if(strcmp(msg,"exit") == 0)
            {
                close(newsockid);
                exit(getpid());
            }
        }
        if(pid!=0)
        {
            memset(msg,'\0',20);
            gets(msg);
            if(send(newsockid,msg,sizeof(msg),0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            if(strcmp(msg,"exit") == 0)
            {
                close(newsockid);
                exit(getpid());
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also here is the client side of things::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int pid,sockfd;
    char msg[20];
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockfd == -1)
        perror("socket");
    myaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port=htons(8888);
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&myaddr,sizeof(myaddr)) == -1)
        perror("connect");
    pid=fork();
    while(1)
    {
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            memset(msg,'\0',20);
            if(recv(sockfd,msg,sizeof(msg),0) == -1)
            {
                perror("recv");
                exit(getpid());
            }
            puts(msg);
            if(strcmp(msg,"exit") == 0)
            {
                close(sockfd);
                exit(getpid());
            }
        }
        if(pid!=0)
        {
            memset(msg,'\0',20);
            gets(msg);
            if(send(sockfd,msg,sizeof(msg),0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            if(strcmp(msg,"exit") == 0)
            {
                close(sockfd);
                exit(getpid());
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try logging the value of errno after recv fails.  The recv [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) lists values of errno and their causes.

Comment: How is 'msg' ever going to equal "exit" after calling send()?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 bugs in the server code.

One is in this line:

```
myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);
```

The `inet_addr` function expects a character string, while `INADDR_ANY` constant is an IP number with all zeros. The server code crashed with segmentation fault for me until this line was corrected (did it really work for you?). The correct usage:

```
myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

Also, `printf` line is not correct - address is not short, but long, also you can't use `%s`  (it would most likely crash). Note, that the compiler (well, `gcc` at least) warns about it - you should always enable and read compiler warnings. As a quick fix I've changed it to:

```
printf("NEW CLIENT ADDR:: %08x",ntohl(clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr));
```

This is fine as long as you can read IP in hex :)

With those fixes it worked fine for me (I mean both server and client) - note, that there can be other bugs, I have to admit I didn't read it too carefuly.

Comment: Ok..I made the changes as suggested by you..but my client on running still gives me the same error..

Comment: OK, let me ask then - what platform is it? Have you tried printing `errno`, as @simonc suggested? Perhaps you should try using strace (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to diagnose the problem?